# Image resizing going wrong

Tags: php, image-resizing

I am trying to resize an uploaded image using the WideImage library.

I need to convert it to the highest resolution possible.
The ouput size should be Width:460px Height:345px

Here is my source for the resize:

```
list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$wpercent = ($w/460)*100;
$hpercent = ($h/345)*100;
if ($wpercent >= 100 && $hpercent >= 100) {
    // Both is over 100% of the allowed size, then resize so the smaller side match.
    if ($wpercent > $hpercent) {
        // height is smallest
        $remove_percent = $hpercent - 100;
    }else{
        // width is smallest
        $remove_percent = $wpercent - 100;
    }
    $new_h_percent = $hpercent - $remove_percent;
    $new_w_percent = $wpercent - $remove_percent;
    $new_w = ($w/460)*$new_w_percent;
    $new_h = ($h/345)*$new_h_percent;
    $img = $img->resize($new_w, $new_h, 'inside');
    $img = $img->crop("center", "middle", 460, 345);
}else {
    // En af dem er for små
    if ($wpercent > $hpercent) {
        // height is smallest
        $add_percent = 100 - $hpercent;
    }else{
        // width is smallest
        $add_percent = 100 - $wpercent;
    }
    $new_h_percent = $hpercent + $add_percent;
    $new_w_percent = $wpercent + $add_percent;
    $new_w = ($w/460)*$new_w_percent;
    $new_h = ($h/345)*$new_h_percent;
    $img = $img->resize($new_w, $new_h, 'inside');
    $img = $img->crop("center", "middle", 460, 345);
}
$img->saveToFile('uploads/tmp/'.$new_name);
```

It does resize, just to a smaller size then I want.

Any ideas?

Also it should crop if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        if ($w != 460 || $h != 345) {
             $img = $img->resize(460, 345, 'inside');
             $img = $img->crop("center", "middle", 460, 345);
        }
        $img->saveToFile('uploads/tmp/'.$new_name);
```

What are you trying to accomplish with all these new_h_percent and new_w_percent?